# GAMS - Economic Dispatch - QCP and NLP

Tags: gams-math, simpowersystems

## I have this code:

If I use NLP i get the results, but using QCP as it was asked to me, I can not get results

anyone can help me  finding the reason?

code:

```
sets  g               generators             / P1*P5 /
  properties      generator properties   / a,b,c,max,min /
  cc(properties)  cost categories        / a,b,c /

table data(g,properties) generator cost characteristics and limits

             a        b         c       max      min
P1          0.19     58.3      1800       155       35
P2          0.13     39.3      3250       195       60
P3          0.08     11.5      4600       165       95
P4          0.07     42.6      5100       305      170
P5          0.14      8.9      3850       280      130

parameter exp(cc) exponent for cost function / a 2, b 1, c 0 /;

scalar  demand    total power demand in MW / 730 / ;

variables
   p(g)     power generation level in MW
   cost     total generation cost - the objective function ;

positive variables p;

p.up(g) = data(g,"max") ;
p.lo(g) = data(g,"min") ;


equations
   Q_Eq1      total cost calculation
   Q_Eq2      constraint - total generation must equal demand ;


 Q_Eq1 .. cost =e= sum((g,cc), data(g,cc)*power(p(g),exp(cc)));
Q_Eq2 .. sum(g,p(g)) =g= demand ;

model problem /all/ ;
```

solve problem using QCP minimizing cost ;

Answer (score 1):

Seems as if the function "power" is treated as nonlinear in general without analyzing the value of "exp", so that it is not allowed for a QCP. You could reformulate Q_Eq1 like this to make it work:

```
Q_Eq1 .. cost =e= sum((g,cc), data(g,cc)*(1        $(exp(cc)=0) +
                                          p(g)     $(exp(cc)=1) +
                                          sqr(p(g))$(exp(cc)=2)));
```

Best,
Lutz